# If else fill variable if empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have lists that are empty and filled in the data. I am trying to the store last element of the list into a variable. If there are elements in the list, it is working fine. However, when I pass in a empty [] list, I get error like: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Which syntax I should be using for []?

```
ids = [
    'abc123',
    'ab233',
    '23231ad',
    'a23r2d23'
    ]

ids = []
# I tried these for empty
final = [ids if [] else ids[-1]] #error
# final = [ids if ids == None else ids == ids[-1]] # error
# final = [ids if ids == [] else ids == ids[-1]] # gives [[]] instead of []
print(final)
```

Basically, if an empty list is in ids, I need it to give []. If there are elements, then give the last element, which is working.

Comment: What do you expect to happen for an empty list?

Comment: you want to check `if ids`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this:

```
final = ids[-1] if ids else None
```

(Replace `None` with the value you'd like `final` to take when the list is empty.)

Answer (score 1):

you can check for a empty list by below expression.

```
data = []
if data:  #this returns False for empty list
    print("list is empty")
else:
    print("list has elements")
```

so what you can do is.

```
final = data[-1] if data else []
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final = ids[-1] if len(ids) > 0 else []
```

This will handle the immediate problem.  Please work through class materials or tutorials a *little* more for individual techniques.  For instance, your phrase `ids if []` doesnt' do what you (currently) seem to think: it does *not* check `ids` against the empty list -- all it does is to see whether that empty list is "truthy", and an empty list evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you wont be able to select the last item if the list is empty and it will rightfully throw an `IndexError`.

Try this example

```
ids = [[i for i in range(10)] for x in range(3)]
ids.append([])

last_if_not_empty = [i[-1] for i in ids if i]
```

Here you filter out the non-empty list by `if i` which is the condition to select not empty lists. From there you can pick out the last elements of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = list[-1] if not len(list)==0 else 0
```